# How to get information from a webpage in android java

Tags: java, android, html, bufferedreader

Ive been trying to get information from a webpage into a string onto my android app. Ive been using this method.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class DownloadPage {

    private static int arraySize;

    public static int getArraySize() throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("http://woah.x10host.com/randomfact2.php");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

        String size = br.readLine();

        arraySize = Integer.parseInt(size);

        return arraySize;
    }



}
```

Ive even included the permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

However i keep getting errors and my app will not launch. It crashes every time i call up the method or the class.

Comment: Could you specify what errors you are getting? Please check your logcat and update your answer. The 2 obvious possible problems are either the accessing a webserver on main thread or the parsing of your _size_ String is wrong. For the first check [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). If it is an error when parsing use Santosh's answer but I'd split on " " and use split[0] instead of assuming it will always be a number of length 2.

Comment: i was getting an error as i was trying to access the webserver from the main thread. i was able to fix that thanks to a previous comment. However, now i am having the problem of the asyntask thread taking too long to gather the information causing the app to crash due to null values

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.
Please try it using AsyncTask for getting that integer.

```
public class DownloadPage {

    private static int arraySize;

    public void getArraySize() throws IOException {

        new RetrieveInt().execute();
    }

    private class RetrieveInt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {


        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String ... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://woah.x10host.com/randomfact2.php");

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

                String size = br.readLine();

                arraySize = Integer.parseInt(size);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                //do something
            }
            return arraySize; // gets 18
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Integer i) {

            // TODO: do something with the number
// You would get value of i == 18 here. This methods gets called after your doInBackground() with output.
            System.out.println(i); 
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. Would you be able to help me use the AsyncTask? ive been trying to use it but i cant seem to understand how it works yet

Comment: This method seems to be working. However, the only problem that rises is that the arraySize is not being gathered fast enough for it to be used. How do i pause the main app til i gather the information from the website?

Comment: You can do anything with that arraysize in `onPostExecute()` (which is result of operation computed by `doInBackground()`).The `onPostExecute()` will on UI thread only after you have received the arraysize. It will not be invoked if the task was cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Issue may be in below code:

```
String size = br.readLine();
arraySize = Integer.parseInt(size);
```

You are trying to parse string to integer. Check if br.readLine() contains only integer value. If string has non-numeric characters then issue will occur.

If you know which part of line contains the size, you can get substring and then parse it to int.

Try below:

```
String resposne = br.readLine();
// If you are sure that array length is only 2 digits.
String length = response.subString(0,2);
arraySize = Integer.parseInt(length);
```

Comment: the first line in the webpage is always a numeric character as i control the content on the web page

Comment: I checked response of webpage mentioned by you. It has below single line: 18 1;test1 2;test2 3;test3 4;test4 5;test5 6;test6 7;test6 8;test7 9;test8 10;test9 11;test10 12;test12 13;afdadsf 14;adfasdf 15;hdgsf 16;adfasdf 17;sfhfsd 18;asdf

Comment: yes. the first 18 in that string is the value that i am trying to obtain from the webpage into my app

Comment: is it because i am trying to access the internet on the same thread as my main thread? if so. any idea on how to create a new thread to solve this

Comment: No. Its because after calling you get complete line which has data other than length. Please check my updated answer which will work if first 2 characters in response maps to array length.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect android app and web server in main ui thread use handeler or aynstask. And use logcat to see webserver data

Answer (score 0):

Since your error is accessing the webserver in the main thread you have to use an AsynTask for it as answered by Amey. You will have a problem then to use the int found in your code unless you update it a little bit.

You can 'pauze' your app to wait for the AsynTask to finish but that would defeat the purpose of using an AsyncTask. AsyncTasks are made to let your app continue without having to wait for slow functions to finish.

To use you array size add in `onPostExecute` a function `DownloadPage.this.useArrayLength(i)` and add to DownloadPage

```
public void useArrayLength(int length){
     //do something with length
}
```

Comment: sorry im kind of new to android java. could you explain to me what the method useArrayLength will do?

Comment: In that function you put the code that previously used getArraySize(). This way you are sure the AsyncTask is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use .wait() in your main so it will process the asynctask first before the main
From this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32026368/7469261